# Use ogr2ogr/ogrinfo to connect to MSSQL on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ogr2ogr, sql-server, ubuntu, ogrinfo

OS: Ubuntu Server 20.04; Software: GDAL/QGIS, ogr2ogr/ogrinfo

My goal is to use ogr to pull data from MSSQL as part of a longer process that I'm working on.

First step is to test out the connection using `ogrinfo` before even attempting the data pull. But using `$ ogrinfo "MSSQL:server=ccgissql01z;database=[];uid=[];pwd=[]"` yields an error message:

```
ERROR 1: Unable to initialize connection to the server for MSSQL:server=[];database=[];uid=[];pwd=[],

Try specifying the driver in the connection string from the list of available drivers:
ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
```

Specifying a driver using `;driver=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server;` doesn't work.

Using `isql` yields a successful connection

Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By playing around with isql and ogrinfo I was able to figure out that what I was missing was `trustservercertificate=yes`.

So the final command looks like this:

```
ogrinfo -so \
"MSSQL:driver=ODBC Driver 18 For SQL Server;\
server=[server];\
trustservercertificate=yes;\
uid=[user];\
pwd=[pass];\
database=[db]"
```